# Compare same and adjacent values in dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have mydata like this:

```
mydata = {'ID':['53','53','53','56','56','56','87','87','87','87'],'Symbole': ['C','C','C','D','D','D','R','K','K','A','T'] ,'Type':['NA - AT', 'AT - CN','CN - UK','NA - AT,'AT - ER', 'AT - ER','EC - FR','FR - GE', 'FR - GE','FR - GE']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=mydata)
```

| ID | Symbole | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 53 | C | NA - AT |
| 53 | C | AT - CN |
| 53 | C | CN - UK |
| 56 | D | NA - AT |
| 56 | D | AT - ER |
| 56 | D | AT - ER |
| 87 | R | EC - FR |
| 87 | K | FR - GE |
| 87 | A | FR - GE |
| 87 | T | FR - GE |

I want search value `Type` if have same and adjacent values.

output:

| ID | Symbole | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 56 | D | NA - AT |
| 56 | D | AT - ER |
| 56 | D | AT - ER |
| 87 | R | EC - FR |
| 87 | K | FR - GE |
| 87 | A | FR - GE |
| 87 | T | FR - GE |

my code:

```
df.groupby(['ID']).apply(lambda x: x.Type == x.Type.shift(1))
```

but error:

```
'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use mask

```
>>> mask =df['m']==df['m'].shift(1)
>>> df[mask]
```